# Laptop not syncing with Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I have a desktop running Maverick, and a laptop running Lucid. Both are supposed to be linked to my Ubuntu One account.

The desktop syncs fine, but when I started the laptop for the first time in a couple of months, it wouldn't sync any more. The Ubuntu One Preferences window either reports "Synchronisation complete" even though no recent files have been downloaded nor have any test files created in the relevant synced folder been uploaded, or it says "Synchronisation in progress", which does not appear to be happening as it stays like this for ages and the lights on my router suggest no traffic is going through.

Have repeatedly tried disconnecting and reconnecting, and removing the device from the account then reattaching it, all to no avail.

Comment: I am also having this problem. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your particular problem, but may have a similar situation. From what I gather, there is a slow syncing ongoing issue: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyIsItTakingSoLongForMyFilesToSync

This might have kicked in when you restarted using your laptop... I did restart and "reinstall" it all several times if it didn't work, but letting it do it's thing over night always somehow proved to be working. I read somewhere as well that it could take a long while before syncing actually started as it was checking structure/syncing new folder structures first.

It is supposed to get better with Natty, let's keep fingers crossed, I will apparently have to wait 40 days for my music library to sync! ;)

Until then, what I added as programs are ubuntuone-indicator and magicicada. Both give more information than just the Disconnected/Connected/Synchronizing... messages ;)
(I am a rather beginner user of Ubuntu, there will probably be much better answers coming your way!)
Good luck!